# Does magento2 use r.js optimization for require.js when deploying static files

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, optimization

I see that javascript contributes a lot to my magento2 page weight (1 mb).

I wonder if it could be optimized with r.js when deploying static content or magento2 already uses an optimization tool.

Does anyone have any experience with that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It could be optimized by using r.js

- Anton Krill showed a basic implementation here
  https://github.com/antonkril/magento-rjs-config - however Magento team is working on new external bundling solution - but I guess it will still take some time
- Shane Osbourne from JH is using r.js with their own way implementation in Magento 2 projects - he created config-gen tool to help devs create build.js file for requirejs optimizer to create bundles - https://github.com/WeareJH/config-gen

Comment: Finally landed in 2.3, see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html#advanced-bundling